# Run the next line immediately in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have some codes here:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Some Codes(1)
  Sample;
  //Some Codes(2)
end;

Function Sample();
begin
  sleep(5000);
end;
```

In this code, after `//Somecodes(1)` Application goes to `Sample` function and waits for 5 seconds then it runs `//Somecodes(2)` right? It means for Unfreezing `Button1` we have to wait for more than 5 Seconds.

Now I want to do something that when the application runs `//Some Codes(1)` and `Sample`, Immediately goes to the next line (`//Somecodes(2)`) so I don't need to wait for 5 seconds to button 1 Unfreez.

How can I do it?

Comment: You want to execute two 'things' *simultaneously*. Hence: You need to use *threads*.

Comment: If we were talking JavaScript, it would be simple - the engine would automatically spawn a new thread for you. But instead, this is Delphi, where you need to implement your own threads when necessary.

Comment: @JerryDodge I thought JavaScript was singlethreaded, except for some specific things (like Ajax requests) that run in the background, generating events. Anyway, Delphi allows for pretty easy threading using anonymous functions.

Comment: @GolezTrol well virtually threaded anyway, allowing two different things to work at the "same time"

Comment: @JerryDodge I think it is just the nature of javascript which is async. So it may seem to run multithreaded but it does not. Probably depends on the host (V8 for example) that runs it, if multithreading is present. But I think without using web workers you only have one thread available.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like Andreas said, you can use threads for this. You might use them with an anonymous procedure like this: (Note: TThread.CreateAnonymousThread appears not to exist yet in Delphi 2010. I address this problem below.)

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      // Chunk of code 1
      Sleep(5000);
      MessageBox(0, 'x', 'x', MB_OK);
    end).Start;

  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      // Chunk of code 2
      Sleep(5000);
      MessageBox(0, 'y', 'y', MB_OK);
    end).Start;
end;
```

You can also implement your own thread class, but using CreateAnonymousThread you can just pass a procedure that is executed in the thread. You can call Start (or Run) to run the thread immediately, and threads created using CreateAnonymousThread free themselves when they are done.

So, both chunks of code will run simultaneously. That means that after 5 seconds you will get two popups right after each other (you can drag aside the topmost to see the other). Also, the button will be responsive directly after it is clicked, while the sleeps are running in the background.

Note though that most of the VCL is not thread safe, so you should be careful not to modify (visual) components in these threads.

**about thread safety**

Like J... mentioned in the comments, it's not just the VCL that is not thread safe. Many code is not, and also your own code needs to be aware of this. 
For instance if I modify the code above slightly, I can let both threads count to a billion and increment a shared integer. You'd expect the integer to reach 2 billion by the time the threads are done, but in my test it reaches just over one billion. That is because both threads are updating the same integer at the same time, overwriting the attempt of the other thread.

```
procedure TForm6.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  n: Integer;
begin
  n := 0;
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var i: Integer;
    begin
      for i := 0 to 1000000000 do
        Inc(n);
      MessageBox(0, 'x', 'x', MB_OK);
    end).Start;

  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var i: Integer;
    begin
      for i := 0 to 1000000000 do
        Inc(n);
      MessageBox(0, 'y', 'y', MB_OK);
    end).Start;

  Sleep(10000); // Make sure this is long enough. The number should appear later than 'x' and 'y'.
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(n));
end;
```

To fix this, you can either *synchronize* the updating (execute it in the main thread), or use *critical sections* to lock the updates. In cases where you are actually just updating in integer, you can also use the `InterlockedIncrement` function. I will not explain these further, because there's plenty of proper documentation and it's beyond the scope of this answer.

Note though, that each of these methods slows down your application by executing the pieces of code after each other instead of simultaneously. You are effectively making the threads wait for each other. Nevertheless, threads are still useful, if you can finetune them so that only small pieces need to be synchronised.

**TThread.CreateAnonymousThread in Delphi 2010**

TThread.CreateAnonymousThread just creates an instance of TAnonymousThread, a specific thread class that executes a given procedure.

Since TThread.CreateAnonymousThread doesn't exist in Delphi 2010, you can just call it like this:

```
  TAnonymousThread.Create(
    procedure
    var i: Integer;
    begin
      for i := 0 to 1000000000 do
        Inc(n);
      MessageBox(0, 'x', 'x', MB_OK);
    end).Start;
```

I don't know if TAnonymousThread itself does exist in Delphi 2010, but if not, you can find it's code below. I hope Embarcadero doesn't mind me sharing it, but it's actually just four simple lines of code.

This class you could just as easy create yourself, but it is declared like below. The constructor takes a single parameter, which is the procedure to execute. It also sets a property that makes the thread free itself when done. The `execute` method just executes the given procedure.

```
type
  TAnonymousThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FProc: TProc;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const AProc: TProc);
  end;

constructor TAnonymousThread.Create(const AProc: TProc);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  FProc := AProc;
end;

procedure TAnonymousThread.Execute;
begin
  FProc();
end;
```

Comment: As a first rule to someone learning, I'd probably go so far as to say that almost *nothing* is thread safe - not just the VCL.  If a thread is touching something that is shared or belongs to something else there almost always needs to be some type of special care taken, above and beyond what one would typically do in a single-threaded context, to avoid concurrency issues.

Comment: @J... You're very right. It's not just the VCL. I explicitly mentioned the VCL, because often people tend to expect that the great and powerful VCL is thread safe while it is not, but you're very right that this goes for every piece of shared data.

Comment: @J... I added a piece of code demonstrating a possible problem of sharing data.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks! but I can't run the application. Dephi (2010) says: "'TThread' does not contain a memeber named 'CreateAnonymousThread'"

Comment: I've made an addition to my answer to address that problem.

Comment: Why not use processes wherever possible instead of threads to avoid all the dangers of thread safety?

Comment: @alcalde because using different processes becomes a bit overwhelming if you intend to do any sort of communication between them. In this case, it appears that OP intends to share some things between those threads - and thread safety is a required art in order to accomplish such things.